# TYPO3 Formhandler finisher does not write to database

Tags: database, forms, webforms, content-management-system, typo3

After the TYPO3 (6.1.7) website of a customer has gone online, the Formhandler forms do not work correctly anymore. They do send an email, but it seems that they do not execute the Finisher_DB for writing into the database anymore.

The TypoScript settings look like this:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {

  debug = 0

  # GENERAL CONFIGURATION
  name = Default
  addErrorAnchors = 1
  formValuesPrefix = formhandler

  fillValueMarkersBeforeLangMarkers = 1

  # ERRORS LAYOUT
  singleErrorTemplate {
    totalWrap = <div>|</div>
    singleWrap = <span class="error">|</span><br />
  }

  errorListTemplate {
    totalWrap = <ul>|</ul>
    singleWrap = <li class="error">|</li>
  }

  validators {
    1.class = Tx_Formhandler_Validator_Default
    1.config {
      fieldConf {
        wish.errorCheck.1 = required 
        alternative.errorCheck.1 = required 
        firstname.errorCheck.1 = required 
        surname.errorCheck.1 = required 
        nationality.errorCheck.1 = required 
        dateofbirth.errorCheck.1 = required 
        phone.errorCheck.1 = required 
        email.errorCheck.1 = required 
        street.errorCheck.1 = required 
        zip.errorCheck.1 = required 
        city.errorCheck.1 = required 
        country.errorCheck.1 = required 
      }
    }
  }

  # Finishers configuration
  finishers {
    1.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail
    1.config {
      checkBinaryCrLf = registrationMessagePlain, registrationMessageHtml
      limitMailsToUser = 10
      admin {
      }
      user {
      }
    }

    2.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_DB
    2.config{
      table = tx_chilifhregistration
      key = uid

      fields {
        timeslot = Sommerplatz
        timeslot_july.mapping = timeslotSummerJuly
        timeslot_august.mapping = timeslotSummerAugust
        timeslot_september.mapping = timeslotSummerSeptember

        wish.mapping = wish
        wishcategory11.mapping = wishCategory11
        wishcategory19.mapping = wishCategory19
        wishcategory22.mapping = wishCategory22
        wishcategorydb.mapping = wishCategoryDb

        alternative.mapping = alternative
        alternativecategory11.mapping = alternativeCategory11
        alternativecategory19.mapping = alternativeCategory19
        alternativecategory22.mapping = alternativeCategory22
        alternativecategorydb.mapping = alternativeCategoryDb

        salutation.mapping = salutation
        firstname.mapping = firstname
        surname.mapping = surname
        nationality.mapping = nationality
        dateofbirth.mapping = dateofbirth
        phone.mapping = phone
        email.mapping = email
        street.mapping = street
        zip.mapping = zip
        city.mapping = city
        country.mapping = country

        salutation2.mapping = salutation2
        firstname2.mapping = firstname2
        surname2.mapping = surname2
        nationality2.mapping = nationality2
        dateofbirth2.mapping = dateofbirth2
        phone2.mapping = phone2
        email2.mapping = email2
        street2.mapping = street2
        zip2.mapping = zip2
        city2.mapping = city2
        country2.mapping = country2
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Interesting enough: if I remove Finisher_Mail and instead write `1.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_DB
    1.config{`, the form does not get displayed at all - I only get an error (no detailed information even in debug mode).

Comment: Maybe have a look at the previous TypoScript (Template → TypoScript Object Browser → Setup). Sounds to me like missing/wrong brackets or wrong conditions in a previous script (destroying the syntax of your formhandler setup afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

You should better use the predef-definition-style for forms. This will save you trouble with multiple forms and is a cleaner implementation.

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.yourformularname { ...config... }
```

You can find a bunch of examples [on the offical site/examples](http://examples.typo3-formhandler.com/start/)

I assume that your admin and user mail-config is only empty because you won´t post any customerinformation?

Did the form work if you fill in every single field?

In my own usecases all field i map with the finisher are required, maybe you should set a ...IfEmpty-option for non-require fields.

[Here](http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/finisher/finisher-db#c935) are the available ifEmpty-options.

Comment: The problem was actually caused by the customer not telling us that he had switched the database. Creating database entries worked flawlessly, I just didn't see it. Thank you nonetheless!